# SQL Trigger call function in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, triggers

Hello i have a problem with my diploma thesis. I should programm a Trigger on Orale, which should execute a java function but here is the Problem:

```
create or replace function callTokengenerator
return boolean
as language java
NAME 'SqlStatements.setTrigger()
     return java.lang.Boolean';


create or replace PROCEDURE generateTokens
is
begin
    callTokengenerator;
end;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tokengenerator AFTER UPDATE OF ACTIVE ON COURSE Declare
    run boolean := generateTokens;
BEGIN
    run;
END;
```

This is my error which is produced

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPllO.png)

Comment: Could you please tell what RDBMS you use? Java-trigger is highly DB-dependend feature

Comment: What "Problem" specifically is there? Please add any error messages verbatim (create-time or run-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"RUN" is not a valid Oracle command. The trigger must call the function directly. See here for proper trigger syntax and construction: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdev/calling-Java-from-database-triggers.html#GUID-5C498DEF-0348-484D-AA26-2A88EF348D5C

Try this:

```
create or replace function callTokengenerator
return boolean
as language java
NAME 'SqlStatements.setTrigger()
     return java.lang.Boolean';

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tokengenerator AFTER UPDATE OF ACTIVE ON COURSE 
DECLARE
    run boolean;
BEGIN
    run := callTokengenerator;
END;
```